# Expand ZFS pool after adding space in XenCenter

Tags: virtual-machine, freebsd, xen

I have a FreeBSD VM that is running in XenCenter. I accidentally set it up with a ZFS file system (doesn't really matter, except that I dont know much about ZFS).

I had initialized the VM with 10GB, but I increased it later to 20GB. THe problem is the extra space didnt show up automatically in the VM. What do I need to do to get that extra 10GB showing up in my FreeBSD VM?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, ZFS doesn't support resizing but you can easily add additional disks or partitions to your ZFS pool using `zpool add`.

In your case, create a partition in the unallocated space and then add it to the pool. The additional space will be available to all ZFS filesystems in the pool.

Another option is to create a new 20GB (or larger) virtual disk and then use `zfs send` and `zfs receive` to move your filesystem(s) to it. But if this is your boot volume, then the first suggestion will be much easier.

Comment: How can I partition the unallocated space, exactly? It doesnt seem to me that it showed up in the VM after i resized it in Xen - or maybe i am using the wrong set of commands to look for it.